# Postman is not fetching data from spring application

Tags: java, spring, postman

I am new to spring.
My spring application is up and running. but when i am using postman to fetch the data. it is throwing 404 not found error. I checked URL but I am not getting where I am going wrong.
can anyone help me.
here is my API class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/nicetry")
public class NiceAPI {
    @Autowired
    private NiceService niceService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/student")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getDetails(){

        List<Student> studentList= niceService.getDetails();
        ResponseEntity<List<Student>> response = new ResponseEntity<List<Student>> 
    (studentList,HttpStatus.OK);
        return response;
    }

}
```

[Here is the Postman Screen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fNwM.png)

Here is the application console

```
2020-04-01 23:50:24.207  WARN 8400 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view 
rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-04-01 23:50:24.704  INFO 8400 --- [           main] 
o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 
'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-04-01 23:50:25.458  INFO 8400 --- [           main] 
o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 5556 
(http) with context path ''
2020-04-01 23:50:25.495  INFO 8400 --- [           main] 
com.saif.NiceTry.NiceTryApplication      : Started NiceTryApplication in 
44.685 seconds (JVM running for 55.867)
2020-04-01 23:52:02.858  INFO 8400 --- [nio-5556-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat]. 
[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 
'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-01 23:52:02.858  INFO 8400 --- [nio-5556-exec-2] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 
'dispatcherServlet'
2020-04-01 23:52:03.276  INFO 8400 --- [nio-5556-exec-2] 
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 417 ms
```

**Help Me**

Comment: are u sure your application is running on 5556 port? Have u set any context path in properties file?

Comment: yes i am sure the applcation is running on port 5556

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the above postman image, you are using 5556 port. By default, Spring Boot uses the 8080 port number. You can however change the port that you are running in the properties file. In Spring Boot, properties are kept in the application.properties file under the classpath. The application.properties file is located in the **src/main/resources directory.**

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_application_properties.htm][1]

[1]: Spring Boot